# Show another image when current image is clicked in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am building an android studio app and this is a torchlight app, the app code is in Kotlin, I have an image in my layout, when the image is clicked the torch will switch on, how can I change the behaviors so that when I click the image, I want it to change to another image?

This is the onclick function

```
Flashlight_btn.setOnClickListener {
            mCameraImpl!!.toggleFlashlight()
        }
```

I tried to use this inside the above code, but shows error
imgButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

What can I do to show another image when button is clicked?

EDITED:

I was able to get it to work by restarting android studio, the problem I am having now is to reverse the process, thanks, how I can reverse the function like when mage is clicked again it shows the former image , is this possible to do?

Comment: That's the right way to do it. What does the error say?

Comment: Please post your log output so others can understand what kind of error your code produced.

Comment: I relaviladted app cache and it worked, thanks, do you know how i can reverse the function like when mage is clicked again it shows the fomer image